# how to log with Spring AOP and SPring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-aop

i use the same class LoggingAspect as in this example tutorial https://www.javaguides.net/2019/05/spring-boot-spring-aop-logging-example-tutorial.html, but when i call a controller methode i get only those messages on console

```
11-05-2020 13:30:27.742 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/appged].log - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
11-05-2020 13:30:27.742 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
11-05-2020 13:30:27.771 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean - Completed initialization in 29 ms
```

la classe le Logging Aspect :
        package com.app.ged.api.aspect;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Aspect for logging execution of service and repository Spring components.
 * 
 *
 */
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     * Pointcut that matches all repositories, services and Web REST endpoints.
     */
    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)" +
        " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)" +
        " || within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void springBeanPointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    /**
     * Pointcut that matches all Spring beans in the application's main packages.
     */
    @Pointcut("within(com.app.ged.api.repository.*)"+
        " || within(com.app.ged.api.service.*)"+
        " || within(com.app.ged.api.controller.*)")
    public void applicationPackagePointcut() {
        // Method is empty as this is just a Pointcut, the implementations are in the advices.
    }

    /**
     * Advice that logs methods throwing exceptions.
     *
     * @param joinPoint join point for advice
     * @param e exception
     */
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()", throwing = "e")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
            log.error("Exception in {}.{}() with cause = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), e.getCause() != null? e.getCause() : "NULL");
    }

    /**
     * Advice that logs when a method is entered and exited.
     *
     * @param joinPoint join point for advice
     * @return result
     * @throws Throwable throws IllegalArgumentException
     */
    @Around("applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        }
        try {
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Exit: {}.{}() with result = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), result);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("Illegal argument: {} in {}.{}()", Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            throw e;
        }
    }


}
```

my logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>
          %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="SAVE-TO-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/log-appGed.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <springProfile name="pc">
    <root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </root>
     <logger name="com.app.ged.api.controller" additivity="false" level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.app.ged.api.service" additivity="false" level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>

  <springProfile name="dev">
    <root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="com.app.api.service" additivity="false" level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>

  <springProfile name="prod">
    <root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="com.app.ged.api.service" additivity="false" level="error">
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

application.properties

```
#logging 
spring.profiles.active=pc
logging.path=C:/logs
```

Comment: could you please try setting the to debug `<springProfile name="pc"><root level="debug">` or add a `<logger name="com.app.ged.api.aspect" ..` under `<springProfile name="pc">` similar to `com.app.ged.api.controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active profile for the run is `pc` and aspect logs are either for `error` or for `debug`

The current root level configuration for profile `pc` is `info` for the application.

Either you may set the root log level as `debug` instead of `info` as follows . This is an application wide setting

```
  <springProfile name="pc">
    <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </root>
    ..
  </springProfile>
```

or set the log level to `debug` for the aspect package classes

```
  <springProfile name="pc">
    <root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="com.app.ged.api.aspect" additivity="false" level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </logger>     
    <logger name="com.app.ged.api.controller" additivity="false" level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.app.ged.api.service" additivity="false" level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE"/>
    </logger>
  </springProfile>
```